# Call an onclick method by clicking a icon in MUI DataGrid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

I am using the default MUI Dialog model as "DialogModel.js" component.
I have an another MUI DataGrid component as below

```
// RulesTable.js

import * as React from 'react';
import { DataGrid } from '@mui/x-data-grid';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
import EditNoteIcon from '@mui/icons-material/EditNote';

import DialogPane from '../components/dialogPane.js';

const columns = [
  { field: 'Truth_ID', headerName: "Truth ID", headerAlign: 'right', align: 'right', width: 130, fontWeight: '14px' },
  { field: 'Action', headerName: "Action", headerAlign: 'right', align: 'right', width: 180 },
  {
    field: 'Description',
    headerName: "Description",
    headerAlign: 'right',
    align: 'right',
    description: 'This column has a value getter and is not sortable.',
    sortable: false,
    width: 1200,
  },
  {
    field: "edit",
    headerName: "Edit",
    sortable: false,
    headerAlign: 'right',
    width: 140,
    disableClickEventBubbling: true,
    renderCell: (params) => {
        return (
            <div className="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center" style={{ cursor: "pointer", paddingLeft: "100px" }}>
                <EditNoteIcon color="secondary" index={params.row.id} />
             </div>
        );
     }
  }
];


export default function RulesTable({RulesTableRowData=[]}) {

  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: '90%' }}>
      <Paper sx={{ width: '100%', mb: 2 }}>
        <div style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
        {Object.keys(RulesTableRowData).length > 0 &&
          <DataGrid
            rows={RulesTableRowData}
            columns={columns}
            initialState={{
              pagination: {
                paginationModel: { page: 0, pageSize: 5 },
              },
            }}
            pageSizeOptions={[5, 10]}

          />
        }
        </div>
        <DialogPane />
      </Paper>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

I need the `DialogPane` to open when an user clicks on the "edit" icon in each row of datagrid and pass the whole row into the model dialog component.

So far I have tried adding an onclick to the `EditNoteIcon` tag and for which the function cannot be written inside the main function.

Answer (score 3):

wrap the EditNoteIcon in a Button tag and in the button tag write the onClick function